# How to select all cells of a UICollectionView programmatically

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I need a function, which "takes" all cells of a UICollectionView, so I can reset the backgroundColor of the cells. Is there a function with which I can do this or do I have to select all cells on their own with?:

```swift
collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following property from [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618056-visiblecells).

```
collectionView.visibleCells
```

And [iterate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689783-foreach) them:

```
collectionView.visibleCells.forEach { cell in
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment imo. If this is to be answer, you need to  explain how this would solve his problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add  `shouldReset` var and do this inside `cellForRowAt`

```
cell.backgroundColor = shouldReset ? UIColor.red  : UIColor.blue
```

whenever you need to change the color do

```
collectionView.reloadData()
```

and manage

`shouldReset` to be `true/false`